# Using dictionary comprehension to create a new dict from selected dict in list-of-dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

Source list of dicts:

```
employees = [{'id':1, 'name': "Jonathan", 'last_name':"Wilkinson", "email":"jwilki@zbigg.com", 'phone':"98753215646", 'role':"Owner"},
            {'id':2, 'name': 'Mary', 'last_name': 'Sue', 'email': 'jjeelasj221@zbigg.net',  'phone': "932342384758", 'role': 'Manager'},
            {'id':3,'name': "Joanna", 'last_name': "Kenderson", 'email':'kjjsdakjae@kkzbigg.com', 'phone': '9876478398478', 'role': 'Employee'}
            ]
```

I would like to create a comprehension that selects a single dict and adds it into a new variable containing a single dict:

```
sel_employee = [employee for employee in employees if employee['id'] == 2]

emp_done = {}
for employee in sel_employee:
    emp_done = employee
```

In other words, how to add everything after the comprehension above into that said comprehension?

As currently without `emp_done` it simply creates a single comprehension, but within a list.

Comment: So essentially you just want to find the first element in the list that matches a condition?

Comment: Is the `id` field unique or not? In other words: is your output always going to contain one item?

Comment: **Why** do you want to use a comprehension to do this? I ask because it doesn't seem to necessary to do what you want.

Comment: Yes, the id field is going to be unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is another way to do it.
It would also set `sel_employee` to `None` if no dictionary is found for which `id == 2` is `True`.

```
sel_employee = next((employee for employee in employees if employee['id'] == 2), None)
```

Comment: this is more than *another* way to do it. This is the most efficient way to do it because as soon as a result that satisfies the condition is found, we stop looping. This does not happen with a list-comprehension.

Comment: Oh, a generator!

Answer (score 2):

Isn't just this what you want?

```
sel_employee = [employee for employee in employees if employee['id'] == 2][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
l = [employee for employee in employees if employee['id'] == 2]
print({1:l[0]}.get(len(l),l))
```

Output:

```
{'id': 2, 'name': 'Mary', 'last_name': 'Sue', 'email': 'jjeelasj221@zbigg.net',
'phone': '932342384758', 'role': 'Manager'}
```

Comment: this does not really make much sense even though it does deliver the desired result. Why would you want to create a new dict? Why not `print(l[0])` directly?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis My answer does not only give `l[0]` it gives all then elems if there is > 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `for` loop and use `dict.update` followed by `break` when your condition is satisfied:

```
emp_done = {}
for employee in sel_employee:
    if employee['id'] == 2:
        emp_done.update(employee)
        break
```

If your condition is never met, `emp_done` will remain an empty dictionary. If your condition is met, `emp_done` will give the first instance only.

Equivalently, you can use `next` with a generator expression as per [@Ozzy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51765267/9209546). However, generator expressions have overheads which may be expensive for larger lists.

Comment: or instead of initializing + updating, simply declaring it inside the `if`.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, you could do this. But then you have a case where `emp_done` may or may not exist as a variable. I'm not an expert on Pythonic-ness, but I'd rather have an empty dict and test `if emp_done` if necessary.

Comment: @jpp Good point. You could however initialize and re-declare\overwrite on the premise that re-declaring might be faster that the `update` method.